# Rails, ruby: does SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64 need to be checked for uniqueness for tokens?

Tags: ruby, random, ruby-on-rails-4, unique

I need unique tokens for users stored in my DB.  At the moment when I generate a token I check it for uniqueness in the DB before using it. Is this a test I actually need to perform or am I wasting time?

I've looked at the [Ruby 2.0.0 API for SecureRandom](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-urlsafe_base64) and it doesn't clarify if I can "trust" the uniqueness or not.

I know no random value can really be "unique" and there's a finite number of possibilities.  But with 32 bits of hex values I feel confident I will never run into the same value again in my app but wanted to ask if anyone knew of a "gotcha" with this situation.

Another consideration is using `SecureRandom.uuid` but that will essentially be the same situation.

```
# usage
user.password_reset_token = Generator.unique_token_for_user(:password_reset_token)

# Performs DB query to ensure uniqueness
class Generator
  def self.unique_token_for_user(attribute)
    begin
      token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(32)
    end while User.exists?(attribute => token)

    token
  end
end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`SecureRandom.uuid` generates uuids. A UUID is 128 bits long, and can guarantee uniqueness across space and time. They are designed to be globally unique, unlike `urlsafe_base64`. See [RFC4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt).

Comment: The answer posted by @tompave is also viable. However, using the SecureRandom.uuid generator doesn't require any additional work, thus I'm marking it as the best solution for my particular question ("guaranteed" way of unique tokens). UUID spec 4 "should" also have 122 random bits (from what I read) so it is not only unique but it is also secure in that users cannot easily "guess" another UUID.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't ensure uniqueness but, as **svoop** said, it's extremely unlikely that you'll get the same result twice.

My advice is: if all you need are random, *unique* and unguessable tokens, and you don't have hundreds of thousands of users, then use it without worrying.

If you **absolutely** want unique tokens (e.g. there is some legal requirement), then combine a unique field associated with the user (e.g. the user email) and a random salt, and hash the result.

A naive implementation would be:

```
require 'securerandom'
require 'digest/md5'


def generate_user_token(user)
  digest(user.email + random_salt)
end


def random_salt
  SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end


def digest(string)
  Digest::MD5.hexdigest string
end
```

Comment: This is a good solution. However, I went with the SecureRandom.uuid implementation because that required less work on my part while still ensuring uniqueness/security :)

Comment: I prefer this solution, alot more secure.

Answer (score 4):

No, you won't see a duplicate in your lifespan.

`32` is the length (in bytes) of the random number generated before it get's converted to an urlsafe base64 string, so chances of a duplicate are roughly 1 to 10'000'000'000'000'000'000'000'000'000'000. That's 10e31 and the universe is only 43e17 seconds old.

Comment: Not 100% true. I just got a duplicate in production. Just lucky I guess? :)